# How to pass negative values to config-set

Tags: drush, configuration

It seems that we can't set negative values with config-set:

```
drush cset block.block.myblock_name weight '-1' --format=string -y
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The (ugly) work-around is:

```
echo '-1' | drush cset block.block.myblock_name weight - -y
```

You don't need to specify that format is string as that is the default.

This seems to be a general problem with Drush commands; values starting with a dash is interpreted as arguments. See bug report for similar issue with vset - https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/issues/378